ReactJS Router Options and splats in a nested route
I have the following nest route:
createRoutesFromElements(<>                             
        <Route path="/:siteid/:route?/login/:cmd?/:id?" element={< LoginLayout/>}>       
            <Route ... />
            <Route ... />
            <Route path="/:siteid/:route?/login/:cmd?/:id?" element={< LoginPage />} />                                
        </Route>
        <Route...more routes />
    </>)
)

But I get the following error:
Absolute route path "/:siteid/:route/login/:cmd" nested under path "/:siteid/:route/login/:cmd/:id" is not valid.
Just to clarify what I am trying to do - I have several different ways to get to the same login...I just want them all routed to the same place:
e.g.:
/siteid/login 
/siteid/route/login
/siteid/route/login/forgot
/siteid/login/reset/1123

are some examples
Still fairly new on the options ans splats.  Any help would be great.

Try below code. I hope this will work.
createRoutesFromElements(<>                             
    <Route path="/" element={< LoginLayout/>}>       
        <Route ... />
        <Route ... />
        <Route path=":siteid/:route?/login/:cmd?/:id?" element={<LoginPage />} />
    </Route>
    <Route...more routes />
</>))

<Route path="/" element={< LoginLayout/>}> this is the root. In the props path what ever you put will be starting of all the sub route you are adding in side the root route.
#HappyCoding
